# How to add PHP part inside PHP

Tags: php

I have a php script which randomly needs to show images based on a specific page title.
So I managed to find some code with an if statement, which works with a single image but when I want it to show random images I don't get it to work.

Example of what works:

```
<?php if(is_page('Page title')){ echo '<img src="/imageA.jpg" />'; } ?>
```

Example of what I am after:

```
<?php if(is_page('Another page title')){ echo '<img src="/image-<?php echo rand(B,C; ?>.jpg">'; }
```

What above needs to do is load randomly imageB.jpg or imageC.jpg
This doesn't happen now because in the url you can see that the code after image- is being rendered wrong, so it can't find the image.

Comment: You have the <?php in the <?php so..... you have to search about when you can use the <?php ?>

Comment: Does a particular page correspond to a particular image or are all images random no matter what the page? Stated a little clearer, when I visit `Page A` should I always get `Image A` or could I get `Image B` or `Image C` etc...

Comment: php is not recursively embeddable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could map out an array of letters and take use of `array_rand()` to randomly select letters inside the mapped letters:

```
<?php
if(is_page('Another page title')) {
    $letters = range('B', 'D'); // generates an array of letters B to D, just change it into your liking
    echo '<img src="/image-' . $letters[array_rand($letters)] . '.jpg" />';
    // take out that `<?php` inside the string, you don't need those
}
?>
```

Sidenote: That `range()` function is optional, if you do not want it, just explicitly set what values that you want randomized:

```
$letters = array('Z', 'X', 'T', 'banner', 'logo', 'header'); // if you don't want that function above
```

Comment: Virtually, it could be any array of anything that could be converted to a string without triggering a error.

Answer (score 0):

use the string contatination operator - '.' - in order to append additional output (such as a function call) to the string.

```
<?php if(is_page('Another page title')){ echo '<img src="/image-' . rand(...) . '.jpg">';}?>
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong way. You are trying to insert php code inside a string, which is not going to be evaluated, but rather just outputted as is.

What you have to do, is to select a random image, for example, that way, using [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function:

```
<?php 

$images = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$random_image = array_rand($images);

if (is_page('Another page title')) {
  echo '<img src="/image-' . $images[$random_image] . '.jpg">'; 
}
```

Comment: Simular to what Ghost submitted as solution and that works like a charme, thanks!